# Possible to RAID with HDDs And an SSD

Tags: raid

So I have never used RAID before, and I want to know if it's possible for me. I'll be buying 2x http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.as...6822136697 of those,

and I already am using a 32gb SSD for my OS drive.

Is it possible to only RAID the HDDs?

I know my motherboard supports RAID, as I've seen options for it in my BIOS.

Thanks!

Edit: Link to motherboard http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813131668

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your motherboard supports it, then yes.  Just makes sure you have the necessary equipment and cables to make it work the way you want.

Comment: Sorry but what other cables do I need besides the SATA Cables to connect to the Motherboard?

Comment: @Austin: It deepens on what kind of RAID you want.  There are several different levels.  Take a look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID#Standard_levels).

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to have a look in the motherboard manual and see which SATA ports support RAID. Then just hook up the drives to two appropriate ports using standard SATA cabling. Make sure you've switched on RAID in the BIOS and then during POST (Power On Self Test) you should see something like "Press CTRL + I to enter RAID setup".

Create a RAID volume using the two disks and then when Windows boots up run 'Computer Management' and have a look at the Disk Management option. You should see a single drive reflecting your new RAID volume. It'll probably need formatting etc.